# Moving data from one range of cells to another with a script Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I asked this question over at the webapps stack exchange, but I didn't get any responses.

Basically, in one sheet I have data in cells C14 through F15, so it's 4 columns and 2 rows of data, 8 cells in total. With a script, I'd like to be able to "copy and paste" the values from these cells into B13:E14 on a different sheet.

I understand how to move values from one cell to another with a script, but I'm having trouble doing it with ranges of values.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[Copying a range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyValuesToRange(Sheet,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) works just like copying a cell, since you can think of a cell as a range with one column and one row.
So you can do something like this:

```
function copyRange() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sourceRange = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('C14:F15');
  const destinationSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  
  // Copy to B13:E14
  sourceRange.copyValuesToRange(destinationSheet, 2, 5, 13, 14);
}
```

Also, this operation is quite common, so you might want to take a look at other questions and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=google%20apps%20script%20copy%20to%20another%20sheet

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`copyTo()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options) method.

```
function copy() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getRange('Sheet1!C14:F15').copyTo(ss.getRange('Sheet2!B13:E14'), { contentsOnly: true });
}
```

Note that you can specify the sheet using [`getSheetByName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)) (or similar) or you can just write it in as part of your range definition using normal A1 notation.

There are other ways to do this. Here's how it could be done using `getValues()` and `setValues()`.

```
function copy() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const values = ss.getRange('Sheet1!C14:F15').getValues();
  ss.getRange('Sheet2!B13:E14').setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: @pwschenkel You can do it that way too. You just need to define two separate ranges (a source & destination). I updated my response to demonstrate how it can be done.